Using odata crossjoin and filter results by array property elements
I use the SAP B1 odata interface and would like to get all ProductionOrders and filter them by checking if I have any item in the ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines array that meets a condition. As of the metadata the ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines array is not a navigation property of ProductionOrders, so I might be on a completely wrong path with the crossjoin.
So far I have the following query:
{{api}}$crossjoin(ProductionOrders, ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines)?$select=DocumentNumber, ItemNo, StartDate, DueDate, ProductDescription, Warehouse, PlannedQuantity, CustomerCode, CompletedQuantity, ProductionOrderStatus, ProductionOrderOriginNumber, Priority&$filter=ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines/DocumentAbsoluteEntry eq ProductionOrders/AbsoluteEntry and ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines/ItemType eq 'pit_Resource'&$expand=ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines($select=ItemType, ItemName, ItemNo)
This lists an array with object that has a separate ProductionOrders and ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines which could also work but the ProductionOrders and ProductionOrderLines listed in the same object are unrelated to each other. The $filter=ProductionOrders/ProductionOrderLines/DocumentAbsoluteEntry eq ProductionOrders/AbsoluteEntry filter must be in the wrong place but I already tried to add it in the expand expression without luck.
